# how to install sound_play

Tags: ros, sound-play, rosdep, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im using ros indigo. i tried this command "`rosdep install sound_play`". It says,

```
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource sound_play
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

Im new to linux.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260933/how-to-install-sound_play/) by [Veera Ragav](https://answers.ros.org/users/29301/veera-ragav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 240 on 2017-05-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The command that you are trying to run installs dependencies of the `sound_play` package. To figure out what those dependencies are, your system needs to be able to find the `package.xml` for the `sound_play` package. So you need to have that package on your machine somewhere. You should be able to type `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-sound-play` to install the package from `apt-get`. Then the above command should work.

Alternatively, you could have a copy of the [source code for the sound_play package](https://github.com/ros-drivers/audio_common) in a workspace, and have sourced the `setup.bash` file for that workspace. Then rosdep would use the `package.xml` located in your workspace instead of the one in /opt/ros/indigo/share.

Note there are many other questions with this same issue on answers.ros.org, these would have been a good place to start. E.g.:

- http://answers.ros.org/question/212453/rosdep-cannot-find-all-required-resources/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/57801/missing-resource/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/75241/install-ros-dependencies-from-apt/

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Veera Ragav](https://answers.ros.org/users/29301/veera-ragav/) on 2017-05-03**:
That worked forme . Thank you.

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-01-31**:
thanks, fixed for me by: sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-sound-play

**Comment by [S.Olatunji](https://answers.ros.org/users/45071/s.olatunji/) on 2019-08-23**:
also worked for me. *sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-sound-play*
Thank you!